# Eclipse generated Maven projects no longer Java projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So I've been creating Maven projects like this for a while.

*New Project > Maven Project

Checked simple Maven project -> next*
*Give it a group and artifact id*
then finish.

Then I'd have a Maven Project ready to go as a Java protect.

Yesterday my Eclipse stopped making these projects Java by default and I think it has something to do with how I was trying to force my Maven protects to no longer use Java 1.5 during build time.

I *can* run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and there is a difference in the `.project` (`.project2` is a copy of the original `.project`) :

```
diff .project2 .project
3,17c3,18
<   <name>example</name>
<   <comment></comment>
<   <projects>
<   </projects>
<   <buildSpec>
<       <buildCommand>
<           <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
<           <arguments>
<           </arguments>
<       </buildCommand>
<   </buildSpec>
<   <natures>
<       <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
<   </natures>
< </projectDescription>
---
>   <name>example</name>
>   <comment>NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.</comment>
>   <projects/>
>   <buildSpec>
>     <buildCommand>
>       <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
>     </buildCommand>
>     <buildCommand>
>       <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
>     </buildCommand>
>   </buildSpec>
>   <natures>
>     <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
>     <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
>   </natures>
> </projectDescription>
```

So I get that I can just run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the project that Eclipse generates, but I'd rather get back to how I was creating projects before. Any ideas how to set how Eclipse generates Maven projects by default (setting default natures)?

I am running:

- macOS Sierra (10.12.2)
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
- Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)

And something new I've noticed is that these new default Maven projects in `Project > Properties > Builders`, the Java Builder is not present in the config and the import menu. The Java Builder is present after `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and in the older projects.

Comment: Which Eclipse version?

Comment: I was using Mars.2 yesterday when this started, and someone at work suggested upgrading to Neon.2 Release (4.6.2). I am using Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) now.

Comment: So what actions did you take to "force Maven to no longer use Java 1.5 during build time" ?

Comment: Not sure anymore. I was doing it sometime last week.

I am about to add some things to the question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what I did to cause this, but I fixed the issue by backing up the projects in my workspace then removing my workspace folder. There must have been some settings in the `.metadata` or `.recommender` folders.

Close Eclipse

```
mv path/to/workspace path/to/workspace2
```

Start Eclipse : It'll look like Eclipse is brand new and clean. I had to set a couple things back up, but this solved my issue with Maven projects not having their `org.eclipse.jdt.core`builder/Natures.